# ListAdapter from a HashMap

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to get my ArrayList of HashMaps to try to get a working ListAdapter. When I run this, I'm getting a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list
```

error. Here's what I have:

gameList is where I'm getting my data from:

```
gameList.toString() returns: [{turn=1, opponent=UserTwo, streak=4, hintX=1234, player=UserOne, solution=MySolution, hintY=5678}, {turn=0, opponent=UserThree, streak=12, hintX=1344, player=UserOne, solution=SolutionTwo, hintY=5428}]
```

My ListActivity class:

```
public class GameListActivity extends ListActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_list);

    String GAME_ITEM = "game";
    String PLAYER_ITEM = "player";
    String OPPONENT_ITEM = "opponent";
    String SOLUTION_ITEM = "solution";
    String HINTX_ITEM = "hintX";
    String HINTY_ITEM = "hintY";
    String STREAK_ITEM = "streak";
    String TURN_ITEM = "turn";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
AppVars gameVars = ((AppVars) getApplicationContext());
gameList = gameVars.getState();

String[] keyList = new String[] { OPPONENT_ITEM, STREAK_ITEM, TURN_ITEM };

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, gameList, R.layout.game_list_item, 
                        keyList, 
                        new int[] {R.id.opponent, R.id.streak, R.id.turn});
setListAdapter(adapter);        

}
```

XML:

game_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Entry"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/streak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Streak"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/turn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/streak"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Your turn!"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

game_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blackboard" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/gameList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is android.R.id.list

So error log tells you everything

You need to add to your `XML` file of `ListView` `android.R.id.list`

```
<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   // next attributes
/>
```

Exactly when your `Activity` extends from `ListActivity`, you should to use this.

Here is info from docs

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

So for more information have look at [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: ah geez, didn't even think of that. Thanks for the quick response! Accepted since you were the first :D

Answer (score 1):

- Mind that When you `extends ListActivity Then your xml file must have listview which id is`
  `@android:id/list`.

USe `@android:id/list`

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extending `ListActivity`, so your view should have list defined with id "list"

See this [link](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php) for working example.

Answer (score 1):

id of list is "@+id/gameList" should be "`@android:id/list`" as you are using `ListActivity...`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your code:

```
setContentView(...)
```

ListActivity handles the `ListView` for you so  you access the `ListView` using `this`.
If you need a more complex layout subclass `Activity` instead.